# Issue while updating a doc when Sharepoint document ID service is activated

Tags: sharepoint

I am using sharepoint 2010 enterprise edition. I have activated Document ID service which will generate a doc Id for each doc when you upload. when i am first time uploading or saving the document it has no issues. It is getting saved. The issue i am facing is when i open the uploaded document and edit or update it and while saving it again it is giving  the webexception "Underlying connection got disconnected. Connection closed prematurely".

I also tried to debug and found the response did not have header.

We were trying to perform in a windows application to edit and save the document.

we are trying to save the document by creating a webrequest.

please provide your idea on this issue.

please see the code below.

"
WebUrl webUrl = UrlToWebUrl(destinationUri);

```
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection methodData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        // Add general request to stream
        methodData.Add("method","put document:" + GetServerExtensionsVersion(webUrl.SiteUrl));
        methodData.Add("service_name",""); 
        methodData.Add("put_option","overwrite,createdir,migrationsemantics"); 
        methodData.Add("keep_checked_out","false");

        HttpWebRequest req = StartWebRequest(GetAuthorURL(webUrl.SiteUrl), methodData);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        System.IO.Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

        RemoveSourceControlProperties(properties);
        WriteDocumentData(reqStream, webUrl.FileUrl, file, properties);

        reqStream.Flush();
        reqStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        try 
        {
            if (!PutDocumentResponseSuccess(GetResponseString(response)))
            {
                throw new FrontPageRPCException("Failed to save document.", destinationUri);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != response) response.Close();
        }
    }
```

"